# is it possible to change the css property of a class dynamically using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a class with css styles already defined. I am now trying to load that page as IFRAME in other site. I want to change the css property of that particular class from the loaded site. Is it possible with jquery. I tried from my end its not getting . can anyone help me...

Comment: can you tell us what all have you tried ? have you tried $( "#mydiv" ).css( "color", "green" );

Comment: So you want to change CSS inside of an iframe?

Comment: If the page is on the same domain as the site it's being included on then you'll be able to do it but otherwise it's not possible to manipulate the contents of the iframe for security reasons.

Comment: This will not work due to the container and iframe being on different domains. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot change style of elements in `iframe` due to [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: I think you should add "..if the iframe is on a different domain".

Comment: This answer is pertinent just if the OP mentions the page and iframe page are on different domains.

Answer (score -1):

you can also use attr attribute to change value of specific attribute of Html.

```
$("img").attr("width","500");
```

Or

```
$("#tagid").attr("width","500");
```

or

```
$(".tagclass").attr("width","500");
```

But in one page you can't change property of child page which is loaded in IFRAME.

Comment: You tried to complement it, but it's still incomplete - so, wrong.

Comment: you can write code in child page but can handle only that page's event. Parent page can handle only its Object.

Answer (score -2):

```
$(".classname").css("propertyname","setvalue");
```

example

```
$(".classname").css("height","50px");
```

for iframe use like

```
$("iframe").contents().find(".classname").css("propertyname","setvalue");
```

reference **[css](http://api.jquery.com/css/)**

**[contains-selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)**

Comment: I don't think this is the answer to the question, sorry

Comment: This would work, because you're selecting the elements of that class and changing their CSS property, but it's not exactly what the OP is asking. By the way, I didn't down vote your answer. Just clarifying.

Comment: It sounds like the OP wants more of a `live` implementation so that all future references to that CSS in subsequent iFrames maintain the css changes.

Comment: @Riturajratan I understand what you're doing.  But what happens when $("iframe").src changes?  Your CSS changes have to be redone.  I believe OP doesn't want that additional step.

Answer (score -2):

You can add or remove class using jquery as following way

```
$(".classname").addClass('new-classname');
$(".classname").removeClass('remove-classname');
```

Comment: Same problem as on @Rituraj ratan answer.